# using Pushgateway to report a Summary metric to Prometheus

Tags: coffeescript, prometheus, summary, prometheus-pushgateway

I'm using Prometheus to monitor an application which is run on a cronjob basis. So, I'm using Pushgateway to make my desired metrics available for Prometheus. One of the metrics is to report how long does a certain task take to finish. Therefore I'm using a Summary to report that. My issue is that I see the same amount reported for each quantile! My understanding was that the reported time for each quantile should be different.

I'm using the followings to `observe()` the time and to `push` my metrics to Pushgateway

```
Summary.labels(myLable).observe(Date.now() - startedAt)

gateway.pushAdd { jobName: 'test' }, (err, resp, body) ->
  console.log "Error!!" if err
```

and here is a screenshot which shows that I'm getting the final time for all quantiles!

[image]

I'd appreciate any comments on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one observation, then a Summary's quantiles will be the same. I'm not sure what you're expecting here instead, a gauge would be the more usual way to report this.